# How to convert data in another form using Regex?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have a huge list with all the countries and cities in this format below.

```
city_states['Finland'] = '|Helsinki||Aland|Etela-Suomen Laani|Ita-Suomen Laani|Lansi-Suomen Laani|Lappi|Oulun Laani';
```

My question is how can I convert it into so that I can run it in an autocomplete script?
I use notepad++ so it lets me to do regex.

```
{ value: 'Finland, Helsinki', data: '' },
{ value: 'Finland, Aland', data: '' },
...
...
...
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the `city_states` variable and then push objects into `result` array.

```js
var city_states = {};
city_states['Finland'] = '|Helsinki||Aland|Etela-Suomen Laani|Ita-Suomen Laani|Lansi-Suomen Laani|Lappi|Oulun Laani';

var result = [];
for (var k in city_states) {
  var c = city_states[k].replace(/^\|/, "").split(/[\|]+/)
  for (var i in c) {
    result.push({
      value: k + ", " + c[i],
      data: ""
    });
  }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: You are great, you saved me hours! PLease tell me how to have the opposite, meaning Helsinki, Finland than Finland, Helsinki?

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos Then don't forget to mark and vote my answer. :-) Just change the `value` option value: `value: c[i] + ", " + k` (`k` is the country, `c[i]` is the city).